# How to click the exact element by finding the ID's in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my code when searching the element through **ID** it is clicking some other element. How can I find the exact element and need to click the same. I'm using **Selenium WebDriver** with **java**.

```
Log.info("Clicking on Overview and Evolution PR link");
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")));
```

[image]

I am trying to click the **Overview & Evolution** tab but it is clicking the **Average Time to Assign** tab

Entire HTML as follows:

```
<li>
    <a id="ext-pr" class="submenu ext-pr" name="ext-pr" href="https://10.4.16.159/reports/">Problem Reports (PR)</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-pr-backlog-age" class=" ext-pr-backlog-age" name="ext-pr-backlog-age"    href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prbacklogage/reports/type/default/">Age</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-timetoassign-prs" class=" ext-timetoassign-prs" name="ext-timetoassign-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_timetoassignprs/reports/type/default/">Average Time To Assign</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-timetodeliver-prs" class=" ext-timetodeliver-prs" name="ext-timetodeliver-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_timetodeliverprs/reports/type/default/">Average Time To Deliver</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-timetoresolve-prs" class=" ext-timetoresolve-prs" name="ext-timetoresolve-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_timetoresolveprs/reports/type/default/">Average Time To Resolve</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-new-prs" class=" ext-new-prs" name="ext-new-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_newprs/reports/type/default/">New</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-open-prs" class=" ext-open-prs" name="ext-open-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_openprs/reports/">Open</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" class=" ext-pr-backlog-evolution" name="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prbacklogevolutiontendency/reports/type/default/">Overview & Evolution</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-pr-domain" class=" ext-pr-domain" name="ext-pr-domain" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prperdomain/reports/">Per Prod/SW Pack/RDT Group</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-pr-tendency" class=" ext-pr-tendency" name="ext-pr-tendency" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prtendency/reports/type/default/">Progression</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-rework-prs" class=" ext-rework-prs" name="ext-rework-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_reworkprs/reports/type/default/">Rework</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="ext-pr-timetosolveprs" class=" ext-pr-timetosolveprs" name="ext-pr-timetosolveprs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_timetosolveprs/reports/type/default/">Time To Solve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Please find the soltion. how to exactly click the element..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this stage, I can't reproduce anything. If the site is publicly visible, please provide the link.

What you can try now is to change your locator and clicking approaches. Apply one of the locators and one of the clicking method each time, you should have at least 7 * 3 = 21 tries.

Base code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")));
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")).click();
```

Different locators:

```
By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") // current, not working
By.cssSelector("#ext-pr-backlog-evolution")
By.cssSelector(".ext-pr-backlog-evolution")
By.cssSelector("href[*='extranet_prbacklogevolutiontendency/reports']")
By.xpath(".//a[@id='ext-pr-backlog-evolution']")
By.cssSelector(".//a[contains(@class, 'ext-pr-backlog-evolution')]")
By.cssSelector(".//a[contains(@href, 'extranet_prbacklogevolutiontendency/reports')]")
```

Different clicking methods:

Normal click

```
driver.findElement(one_of_the_locators_above).click();`
```

Actions click

```
new Actions(driver).click(driver.findElement(one_of_the_locators_above)).perform();
```

JavaScript click

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(one_of_the_locators_above));
```

Comment: I followed the way you have mentioned but there also it is showing the same error.

Comment: I have posted the entire HTML. Please suggest me any solution

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is unique, you just need to use:

```
$('#ext-pr-backlog-evolution').click(function() {
     // Your code here
});
```

Comment: I won't downvote this but this is totally incorrect. The context here is Selenium. I'm not downvoting it because OP has actually put in a jQuery tag (so it's not your fault really) - which I have now removed.